# How to handle implicit and explicit type conversions between const and non-const fancy pointers?

Tags: c++, casting, constants, const-cast, fancy-pointers

Given the type definitions

```
using ConstHandle = MyEntity const*;
using Handle = MyEntity*;
```

it is possible to conduct the following type conversions:

1. `Handle` → `ConstHandle`   (implicit)
2. `ConstHandle` → `Handle`   (explicit via `const_cast`)
3. `Handle*` → `ConstHandle*` (explicit via `const_cast`)
4. `ConstHandle&` → `Handle&` (explicit via `const_cast`)

**Can I achieve similar behaviour with handles based on IDs instead of pointers?**

Cases 1 and 2 can be easily solved, e.g.

```
struct ConstHandle
{
   int id;
};

struct Handle
{
   operator ConstHandle() const { return { id }; }
   int id;
};

Handle const_handle_cast(ConstHandle h) { return { h.id }; }
```

Case 3 can *almost* be solved by deriving `Handle` from `ConstHandle`, i.e.

```
struct ConstHandle
{
   int id;
};

struct Handle : ConstHandle
{
};
```

Here, *almost* refers to the fact that, now, the conversion `Handle*` → `ConstHandle*` is implicit rather than explicit.

**Is there a *legal* solution that incorporates case 4?** *Legal* particularly refers to approaches that do *not* imply a violation of the *strict aliasing rule*.

Comment: Generally const_cast isn't a good idea, do you have a specific reason to need to do this?

Comment: `using ConstHandle = const Handle`?